# Pythonanwhere Changes the Page Layout

Tags: python, templates, format, pythonanywhere, page-layout

I've uploaded a basic blog_website to pythonanywhere for some purposes and what? It spoiled the navigation bar and other format settings where I have no clue.

There is the screenshots: [localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5O2F9.png) [pythonanywhere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdG7m.jpg)

I couldn't find any settings, template file to upload here as it makes no sense to me but I like to share them with you once you ask for it.

Comment: I've been using PA for years, and I can assure that they are not responsible for that. Most likely you are not referencing a CSS file correctly. Try opening the DevTools and see if there's any CSS file with a 404 code error.

Comment: Aha! I see that and solved my problem. I've been getting up to the settings.py file for root directories as I've tried several ways. I appreciate your help, thanks a lot!